# How to set Original Estimate field to value of Remaining work in TFS 2010 template

Tags: action, field

We removed the Original Estimate field from the Task work item form in the Agile process template because we found it "guided" to much when updating the Remaining Work and Completed Work fields. Remaining+Completed was always quite near the value of Original Estimate.

What I would want is that then the task gets a remaining work set the same value would be set in the original estimate field. The field is still available even though it's not shown in thu UI and I could easily compare estimate vs completed work in e.g. Excel.

Is it possible to create and action of some sort so that when saving a task it would check (in pseudocode)

```
if (RemainingWork was 0 OR empty) AND RemainingWork>0 AND (OriginalEstimate is 0 OR empty) then
OriginalWork=RemainingWork
```

-Mathias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this add-on is what you are looking for.

http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/

It allows dynamic calculation of field values.